# Late data handling | Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam

Late data which has missed the window and `.withAllowedLateness` period is dropped off from the pipeline as documented [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#watermarks-and-late-data)

I have a few questions on this behavior:

1. How to handle late data which is dropped off from the pipeline? Can we add default behavior? Say all late data should be logged somewhere like catch-all bucket?
2. Can we have a Metric(Google Dataflow Metrics/Beam) to say how many of these messages are dropped off from pipeline due to huge latency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. In general we define late data as elements that, by the time they arrive, we just prefer to drop them and do not want to process any further. As far as I know, adding extra functionality to handle those messages would require substantial effort to modify the Java SDK. However, if you just want to log them this is done by the [`LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.17.0/runners/core-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/core/LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java#L138) code, which is [responsible](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/website/src/contribute/runner-guide.md#dofnrunners) for dropping data from expired windows:

```java
for (WindowedValue<InputT> input : concatElements) {
  BoundedWindow window = Iterables.getOnlyElement(input.getWindows());
  if (canDropDueToExpiredWindow(window)) {
    // The element is too late for this window.
    droppedDueToLateness.inc();
    WindowTracing.debug(
        "{}: Dropping element at {} for key:{}; window:{} "
            + "since too far behind inputWatermark:{}; outputWatermark:{}",
        LateDataFilter.class.getSimpleName(),
        input.getTimestamp(),
        key,
        window,
        timerInternals.currentInputWatermarkTime(),
        timerInternals.currentOutputWatermarkTime());
  }
}
```

Note that the log has `DEBUG` level so you might not see it. As explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#SettingLevels), to override the level in Dataflow, you can use `--defaultWorkerLogLevel=DEBUG` or, even better, specify a particular class such as `--workerLogLevelOverrides={"org.apache.beam.sdk.util.WindowTracing":"DEBUG"}`. Choosing your keys wisely can help expose information to identify the dropped message (i.e. data lineage).

2. As can be seen in the previous snippet, [`droppedDueToLateness`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.17.0/runners/core-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/core/LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java#L105) is a Counter metric that is incremented each time we drop an element: `droppedDueToLateness.inc();`. You can monitor it using Stackdriver with resource type `dataflow_job` and metric `custom.googleapis.com/dataflow/droppedDueToLateness`.

[image]

Comment: @gulliem Looks like this is poorly documented in the Beam page. Thanks for sharing this stuff!

Comment: If you're using Python, unfortunately, This feature is not yet available in the Apache Beam SDK for Python.

Comment: Can you override or inherit the `LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner` class? and use your own implementation?