# apache beam (python SDK): Late (or early) events discarded and triggers. How to know how many discarded and why?

Tags: apache-beam

I have a streaming pipeline connected with a PubSub subscription (with around 2MLN elements every hour. I need to collect them in a group and then extract some information.

```
def expand(self, pcoll):
    return (
            pcoll |

            beam.WindowInto(FixedWindows(10),
                            trigger=AfterAny(AfterCount(2000), AfterProcessingTime(30)),
                            allowed_lateness=10,
                            trigger=AfterAny(
                                AfterCount(8000),
                                AfterProcessingTime(30),
                                AfterWatermark(
                                    early=AfterProcessingTime(60),
                                    late=AfterProcessingTime(60)
                                )
                            ),
                            allowed_lateness=60 * 60 * 24,
                            accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
| "Group by Key" >> beam.GroupByKey()
```

I try my best to NOT miss any data. But I found out that I have around 4% missing data.
As you can see in the code I trigger anytime I hit 8k elements or every 30 seconds.
Allowing lateness 1 day, and it should trigger both if the pipeline is analyzing early or late events.

Still missing those 4% though.  So, is there a way to know if the pipeline is discarding some data? How many elements? For which reason?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59852691/late-data-handling-apache-beam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I see you have two triggers in the sample code, I assume this is a typo, though.

It looks you are dropping elements due to no using [`Repeatedly`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.28.0/apache_beam.transforms.trigger.html?highlight=repeatedly#apache_beam.transforms.trigger.Repeatedly), so all elements after the first trigger get lost. There's an official doc on this from [Beam](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sr8Y8jgk8TPToJerWgcdmfaRSoTzPCQPnuW9F73yTpE/edit).

Allow me to post an example:

```
test_stream = (TestStream()
               .add_elements([
                    TimestampedValue('in_time_1', 0),
                    TimestampedValue('in_time_2', 0)])
               .advance_watermark_to(9)
               .advance_processing_time(9)
               .add_elements([TimestampedValue('late_but_in_window', 8)])
               .advance_watermark_to(10)
               .advance_processing_time(10)
               .add_elements([TimestampedValue('in_time_window2', 12)])
               .advance_watermark_to(20)  # Past window time
               .advance_processing_time(20)
               .add_elements([TimestampedValue('late_window_closed', 9),
                              TimestampedValue('in_time_window2_2', 12)])
               .advance_watermark_to_infinity())


class RecordFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(
        self,
        element=beam.DoFn.ElementParam,
        timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):

        yield ("key", (element, timestamp))



options = PipelineOptions()
options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

with TestPipeline(options=options) as p:
    records = (p | test_stream
                 | beam.ParDo(RecordFn())
                 | beam.WindowInto(FixedWindows(10),
                                   allowed_lateness=0,
                                   # trigger=trigger.AfterCount(1),
                                   trigger=trigger.Repeatedly(trigger.AfterCount(1)),
                                   accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
                 | beam.GroupByKey()
                 | beam.Map(print)
               )
```

If we have trigger `trigger.Repeatedly(trigger.AfterCount(1))`, all elements are fired as they come, with no dropped element (but `late_window_closed` which is expected as it was late):

```
('key', [('in_time_1', Timestamp(0)), ('in_time_2', Timestamp(0))])  # this two are together since they arrived together
('key', [('late_but_in_window', Timestamp(8))])
('key', [('in_time_window2', Timestamp(12))])
('key', [('in_time_window2_2', Timestamp(12))])
```

If we use `trigger.AfterCount(1)` (no repeatedly), we only get the first elements that arrived in the pipeline:

```
('key', [('in_time_1', Timestamp(0)), ('in_time_2', Timestamp(0))])
('key', [('in_time_window2', Timestamp(12))])
```

Note that both `in_time_(1,2)` appear in the first fired pane because the arrived at the same time (0), were one of them appear later it would have been dropped.

Comment: I did see the Repeatedly trigger, but since it was not really documented well, I wasn't sure about if they would be stuck in a window "repeating forever" or go on. But your answer and the doc you linked (where did you find it?)... cleared everything up. Thank you! 
Extremely clear.

Comment: The doc is linked when using triggers without repeatedly in Java, it actually throws an exception. I guess this does not happen yet in Python because StatefulAndTimelyDoFns being relatively new. I guess it's worth adding a warning or something in Python