# Dataflow - Fixed Window- AfterProcessingTrigger

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using a fixed window of 60 seconds with a trigger time 10 second. I am facing few unexpected results. Could you please help me in understanding how exactly it works.All the detail I have provided below.

My Input to the pubsub topic is :

```
*name* *score*  publish timestamp(every 5 seconds I am publishing one element)
Laia    30  2021-04-10 09:38:29.708000+0000     
Victor  20  2021-04-10 09:38:34.695000+0000     
Victor  50  2021-04-10 09:38:39.703000+0000     
Laia    40  2021-04-10 09:38:44.701000+0000     
Victor  10  2021-04-10 09:38:49.711000+0000     
Victor  40  2021-04-10 09:38:54.721000+0000     
Laia    40  2021-04-10 09:38:59.715000+0000     
Laia    50  2021-04-10 09:39:04.741000+0000     
Laia    20  2021-04-10 09:39:09.867000+0000     
Laia    20  2021-04-10 09:39:14.749000+0000
```

My Code :
window_withTrigger = (words

```
              | "window" >>     beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(60),
                                            trigger=AfterProcessingTime(1 * 10),
                                            accumulation_mode= AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING)
                | "Group" >> GroupByKey())
```

window_withoutTrigger =     (words

```
                               | "window" >>     beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(60))
                               | "Group"         >> GroupByKey())
```

O/P for window_withTrigger:

```
Laia    [30]    
Victor  [20, 50, 10, 40]    
Laia    [50, 20, 20]
```

O/P for window_withoutTrigger:

```
Laia     [30, 40, 40]   
Victor  [20, 50, 10, 40]    
Laia    [50, 20, 20]
```

Output without trigger I am getting all the 10 elements that I published to the topic and with trigger I am getting 8 elements. I notice with trigger it does not emit results in 10 seconds if there is no change in the key item i.e only if the i/p name is changing from laila to victor it emits result and once it emits for one key in a window it does not emit again even if I publish with the same key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably dropping the elements because of not using `Repeatedly`.

Here you have another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66357805/apache-beam-python-sdk-late-or-early-events-discarded-and-triggers-how-to/66364990#66364990) where this is explained. Basically the idea is that if you don't add `Repeatedly`, the trigger would only fire once.

[Official doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sr8Y8jgk8TPToJerWgcdmfaRSoTzPCQPnuW9F73yTpE/edit).

Comment: Thanks Iñigo !!  with this the missing data issue is surely resolved. Could you please help me  understanding below query: with the input data provided above :

> the time at which the trigger will be fired and what would be the output
<  >
According to me the first element is pushed at 09:38:29 so trigger should be fired at
09:38:39  and the output should be  Laila :[30] and victor : [20,50] . But somehow its not the case.

Comment: By reading the input, I think you are right. Could you provide a test stream where that happens? So i can test myself locally